# How can i check what messages have been posted to my group page on facebook?

Tags: c#, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have this mode that send/post a message/text to my group page on facebook:

```
private string PostFacebookWall(string accessToken, string message)
    {
        var responsePost = "";
        try
        {
            var objFacebookClient = new FacebookClient(accessToken);
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            parameters["message"] = message;
            responsePost = objFacebookClient.Post("/" + GroupId + "/feed", parameters).ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            responsePost = "Facebook Posting Error Message: " + ex.Message;
        }
        return responsePost;
    }
```

Then i have a method that check make sure not to post same message/text twice:

```
private Hashtable alreadyPost = new Hashtable();

    private void PostMessage()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < ScrollLabel._lines.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < WordsList.words.Length; x++)
            {
                if (ScrollLabel._lines[i].Contains(WordsList.words[x]) && !alreadyPost.ContainsKey(ScrollLabel._lines[i]))
                {
                    lineToPost = ScrollLabel._lines[i];
                    string testline = lineToPost + Environment.NewLine + ScrollLabel._lines[i + 1];
                    PostFacebookWall(AccessPageToken, testline + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "נשלח באופן אוטומטי כניסיון דרך תוכנה");
                    alreadyPost.Add(lineToPost, true);
                    numberofposts += 1;
                    label7.Text = numberofposts.ToString();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then i have a timer tick that there i updte the text and also post the messages/texts every 10 seconds:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter += 1;
            label9.Text = counter.ToString();
            label9.Visible = true;
            if (counter == 10)
            {
                scrollLabel1.Reset();
                scrollLabel1.Text = " ";
                scrollLabel1.Invalidate();
                this.scrollLabel1.Text = combindedString;
                scrollLabel1.Invalidate();
                counter = 0;
                PostMessage();
            }
        }
```

The problem is when im running the progrem over and over again it will keep posting the same posts since it dosent know what posts are already exist on my group page.
I need to find somehow how to check/get the posts that are already exist on my group page in my facebook and then add this posts each time im running the program to the List: alreadyPost so it wont post them over and over again each time im closing and running the program again.

I could write the content of the List alreadyPost to a text file and read the text file back to the List i the constructor but that dosent make sure or check if the posts already exist on my group page.

How can i solve it ? The problem is how to know if the posts that have been posted are exist on my group page. No if my program sent it or if they were successfuly sent but if they are in my group page then dont post it again when im running the program over again.

Comment: Also the problem could be if im deleting a post on my facebook group page then how my program will know if i deleted it if to send it again or not ? So i want to check in the constructor and also in the timer tick event if the post exist on the group page dont post it again but also in the timer to check each 10 seconds if the post that is alreadyPost exist on the group page also dont post it again but if i deleted the post manualy on my facebook then do post it again. It dosent matter now why i have deleted the post but i need to find how to check/get existing posts on my group page.

Comment: I saw now there is an event called postcompleted . Maybe i should use this event to make sure that the post was posted and the if it does i add this to a text file and then read this post id from the text file and add it to the list alreadyPost that way i know this posts exist on the facebook ?